# Why does my code doesn't work when i declare a variable outside the for loop?

Tags: c, loops, pointers, linked-list, variable-declaration

I want to get the intersection of two linked lists but when i declare the iterators outside the for loop it just doesn't work

```
// THIS WORKS FINE

for (SList iter1 = list1 ; !slist_empty(iter1); iter1 = iter1->next) {
  for(SList iter2 = list2 ; !slist_empty(iter2); iter2 = iter2->next) {
    if(comp(iter1->data, iter2->data)) {
      result = slist_add(result, iter1->data);
    }
  }
}

// THIS DOESN't
SList iter1 = list1 ;
SList iter2 = list2 ;

for (; !slist_empty(iter1); iter1 = iter1->next) {

  for(; !slist_empty(iter2); iter2 = iter2->next) {
    if(comp(iter1->data, iter2->data)) {
      result = slist_add(result, iter1->data);
    }
  }
}
```

im compiling with -std=c99

Comment: _just doesn't work_ can you be more clear ? you cannot compile ? the execution fails ? What is the definition of SList ? The tag is C, is really C or C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version you go through `list2` for every item in `list1`.

In the second version you only go through `list2` for the first item in `list1`. You need to "reset" `iter2` to the start of `list2` each time.